# Running a project in meteor, Errors prevented startup. While downloading accounts-base@1.4.2...: > error: certificate has expired

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

This is the error that appears in the **terminal**:

> ```
> Errors prevented startup:
>    
>    While downloading accounts-base@1.4.2...:
>    error: certificate has expired
> ```

and so more messages of this type.
It's like I need to install more packages or updates.
I was already at the bottom of my system.
I have meteor version 2.15.
node version v14.21.3
nvm 0.39.7
I use Ubuntu 20.4 LTS 64 bits.
I tried meteor reset and then meteor update.
I tried installing meteor again.
I installed it with nvm.